# Increase Vertical Distance Between Line 1 and Line 2 of a Multi Line Bullet in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm making a bulleted list LaTeX using itemize. One of the bullets wraps over onto a new line. How do I adjust the spacing between the two lines of this bullet to be the same as the spacing between individual bullets? For example:

- Foo
- Bar
- The jagged blueberries danced along the frisky cheese wheel under the moonlit sky while the big man sang his song in a blue shirt.

How do I adjust the spacing between "jagged" and "shirt" in bullet 3 to match the spacing between "Foo" and "Bar". Even if the spacing appears identical in this example, in my LaTeX document they are slightly off.

Comment: Please share a [minial reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including all packages you are using.

Comment: The quickest way to achieve this is to set the line(s) as a separate `\item[]`. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/4PKLj9gd) which generates [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irOrz.png).